# How to get image source value

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

Let's say I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="out-radio">
    <div class="in-radio">
        <input type="radio" value = "12345">
        <label
        <span           
            <div
                <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/test001.jpg">
            </div>
        </span
    </label
    </div>
    <div class="in-radio">
        <input type="radio" value = "12346">
        <label
        <span           
            <div
                <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/test002.jpg">
            </div>
        </span
    </label
    </div>
    <div class="in-radio">
        <input type="radio" value = "12347">
        <label
        <span           
            <div
                <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/test003.jpg">
            </div>
        </span
    </label
    </div>
    <div class="in-radio">
        <input type="radio" value = "12348">
        <label
        <span           
            <div
                <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/test004.jpg">
            </div>
        </span
    </label
    </div>
    <div class="in-radio">
        <input type="radio" value = "12349">
        <label
        <span           
            <div
                <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/test005.jpg">
            </div>
        </span
    </label
    </div>
</div>
```

If I want to display the `value` for the selected radio button, I would do it like this:

```
browser.element(:xpath, '//*[@class = "in-radio"]').inputs.each {|input| puts value if input.checked?}
```

How would I display the `src` for the selected radio button?
Is there any way I could put:

```
browser.element(:xpath, '//*[@class = "in-radio"]').(inputs,imgs).each {|input,img| ...}
```

Comment: The HTML is not that great, I have to edit it to put it on public.

Answer (score 5):

If you select the last radio button:

```
browser.radios.each {|radio| p radio.parent.img.src if radio.set?}
# => "http://s3.amazonaws.com/test005.jpg"
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"img"}
This maybe due to my real HTML code is little different from what I posted here.  I have edited the HTML..  Sorry and Thanks